# BrowserField2 : Focus through all the links in the BrowserField

Tags: blackberry

I'v been looking for some time now.

Like many others I cannot figure out how to enable a simple navigation inside a BrowserField. I want the focus to go through all the links (or anything that is focusable) inside the browserfield as we roll the trackwheel in any direction. And when the focus reach the top or the bottom of the browserfield, it would go to the next or previous field.

The 3 different navigation modes of the BrowserFieldConfig are not what I'm looking for. "NONE" would be the closest but I need to be able to focus on the links.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

navigation mode focusable is not available for OS 5, check BlackBerry WebWorks to do an app with focusable mode on OS 5.